# OneLogin SSO with multiply idPs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saml-2.0, service-provider, onelogin

One of our clients has OneLogin as identity provider and we were asked to implement SSO.
My question is, how could I implement multiple idPs(few clients) on OneLogin using same "sign in with OneLogin" option?

Thanks.

Comment: If OneLogin is IdP, then it's a single entity for your single customer (SP apps) to them. What you are trying to do here?

Comment: Let's say customer1 has an account on OneLogin and customer2. Both idP. We are SP. I would like to create SSO for both displaying "connect with OneLogin" instead of "connect with customer1" and "connect with customer2". Is it possible? Is there may be some way to pull the metadata dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Most implementers either handle this via either url or subdomain.

e.g. customer1.yourservice.com and customer2.yourservice.com or www.yourservice.com/customer1/login www.yourservice.com/customer2/login

From there you can know if that customer had OneLogin as the IDP enabled and just automatically do the SAML flow (or any IDP, for that matter)

Answer (score 1):

On a multi-tenant environment you should be able to link each tenant with an IdP, you can do it by linking a specific SAML settings to a tenant.

I don't know if your multi-tenant solution is based on different subdomains, or different url path or based on a tenant id... but since you are able to identify the tenant you should be able to link a tenant with an specific SAML Settings, and store them in a database or a file to be able to get it them later.  You must have a different Entity ID and ACS URL for each tenant so you will be able to receive the SAML Response in the right place and validate with the right settings

If you are currently offering 1 unique login page for all your tenants, you should split it and offer a custom login page per tenant, the alternative is to just add at the global login page  a "Login by SAML" link that after click will move the user to a "discovery tenant" page, where the user should select in what tenant he is trying to access. If the userid is unique per tenant, you can ask it and based on it identify the tenant (this is how currently Google works).